# How to do I decrypt back to string value for RSA c++

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am having an hard time decrypting using the RSA algorithm all I am getting from the result of the decryption function is an numerical value and not the actual character string value the user inputted.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    long int v2 = (rand() % 900 + 800);
    long int v1 = (rand() % 900 + 800);
    for (int i=v1; i<v1+100; i++)
    {
        bool prime=true;
        for (int j=2; j*j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                prime=false;
                break;
            }   
        }
        if(prime){
            // v2 = int a[i];
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    int d;
    int e = 3;
    int p = 1087;
    int q = 1091;
    int p1 = (p-1);
    int p2 = (q-1);
    int phi = p1*p2;
    int n = p*q;
    int d_value;
    cout<<"phi is " <<phi<<endl;
    cout<<"n is " <<n<<endl;

    int sk;
    //Simple iteration to find d using forloop. E*Dmodn = 1
    for(int i=1;i>0;i++)
    {
        int x=i*e;
        d=x%n;
        if(d==1)  //E*Dmodn = 1
        {
            d_value=i;
            cout<<"\n\n Private Key ::"<<d_value;
            break;
        }
    } // end of forloop

    // User Input, option starts here
    string Message;
    int numerical_value_msg[Message.length()]; // Dynamic array allocation
    cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
    getline (cin,Message);
    cout << Message << "!\n";
    for(int i = 0; i<Message.length(); i++){ // Trying to transfer string of character to numerical value
        numerical_value_msg[i] = Message[i];
    }
    cout<<numerical_value_msg<<endl; // Output of Numerical Value of Message

    // Encryption starts here
    int size = sizeof(numerical_value_msg);
    int encryption_value[100];
    int m_e_value[100];
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        m_e_value[i] = pow(numerical_value_msg[i],e); //exponent from math.h
        encryption_value[i] = m_e_value[i]%n;
        //cout<<"e"<<encryption_value<<endl;
         cout<<"e"<<encryption_value<<endl;
        }

    //Decryption Value
    int size2 = sizeof(encryption_value);
    int c_d_value[100];
    char actual_value[Message.length()];

    for(int i=0; i<Message.length();i++){
        cout<<"DValue"<<d_value<<endl;
        c_d_value[i] = pow(encryption_value[i],d_value);
        actual_value[i] = (m_e_value[i]%n)+96; // + 96 to convert it to Letter value
    }
    cout<<"Actual value"<<actual_value<<endl;
}
```

MyOutput reads as such

```
Private Key ::395306 Please, enter Text TO convert: 
Hello Hello!
0x7fff5fbfedd0
encrytion value is 0x7fff5fbff620
encrytion value is 0x7fff5fbff620
encrytion value is 0x7fff5fbff620
encrytion value is 0x7fff5fbff620
encrytion value is 0x7fff5fbff620
```

Actual value`\375\243\2432`   --> how do I convert this to letter format.

Comment: "`int numerical_value_msg[Message.length()]; // Dynamic array allocation`" That's what you think. It's actually a compiler error on most compilers.

Comment: @user4581301 it makes no difference at all.. :(

Comment: Code and output reformatted to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

First problem in the code is Undefined Behaviour at:

```
string Message;
int numerical_value_msg[Message.length()]; // Dynamic array allocation

// Lines skipped
numerical_value_msg[i] = Message[i];
```

`Message` is always empty when `numerical_value_msg` array created. After that `Message` gets it's value and `for` loop access memory out of array bounds in `numerical_value_msg`. I suggest to replace `int[]` type with `vector<int>`. C++ standard [guarantees](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) that elements stored contiguously there. It means you can get the raw array when required.

You could specify the `operator<<` to print data to the `cout`:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& v) {
  if (!v.empty()) {
    out << '[';
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(out, ", "));
    out << "\b\b]";
  }
  return out;
}
```

I assume you use `vector<int>` for your encrypted values. In this case operator above will output values instead of pointer address `0x7fff5fbfedd0`.

> Actual value\375\243\2432 --> how do I convert this to letter format

You don't need to add any `96` constant to the decrypted value. After decryption you should get the original value. The reason why it's not happen is the `int` value overflow. Recheck your calculation and the resulting values, e.g. you need to change `c_d_value` type to `std::vector<unsigned long long> c_d_value`.